# How to declare a protocol with a function that returns NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui, protocols, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to declare a protocol that has function which must return NavigationLink. But when I try this it returns an error "Reference to generic type 'NavigationLink' requires arguments in <...>"

```
protocol Protocol: class{
    func function() -> NavigationLink
}
```

(Jessy)

```
class BeersListRouter: BeersListRouterProtocol{
    typealias Label = Text
    typealias Destination = View
    
    func getBeerDetailsView(for beer: Beer) -> NavigationLink<Label, Destination>{
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NavigationLink is a generic type, with two placeholders](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink). You need to account for them.

```swift
protocol Protocol: AnyObject {
  associatedtype Label: View
  associatedtype Destination: View
  
  func function() -> NavigationLink<Label, Destination>
}
```

Comment: When I implement this I receive "Protocol 'BeersListRouter.Label' (aka 'View') as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself". Maybe I implement this incorrectly(I added it in question description)